# ADC conversion using a Datasheet

Tags: current, digital-logic, adc, vhdl

Is it possible to find a corresponding digital value for an analog current value(Amps) using the ADC component datasheet? If yes, what are the parameters I should consider?

Thank you!

Comment: This all depends on how you're measuring the current (you'll need to convert it to a voltage first, perhaps using a shunt resistor), your ADC reference voltage, the resolution of your ADC, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I haven't stumbled upon a direct current to digital converter yet, so I'll give an approach for an ideal situation:

The current you want to measure is run through a shunt resistor and will create a voltage across it according to ohms law. Let's say you want to measure a current of \$1A\$ and you have a shunt resistor of \$1\Omega\$. The voltage drop will be \$1V\$.

Now if you use an ADC with 12 bits (0-4095 as digital value) and it uses a reference voltage of \$2.5V\$.

You can get the output of the ADC:
$$ Digital result= \frac{Input Voltage}{Reference Voltage} \times 4095 = \frac{1V}{2.5V}\times 4095 \approx 1638$$

Now this will be the ideal value. In a real circuit you will have non-linearity errors from the ADC, the voltage reference won't be exactly \$2.5V\$ and the resistor won't be \$1\Omega\$. So there will be some deviation from it.

Well I took some shortcuts, there are ADCs which have +/- capable inputs and stuff like that, but the principle isn't that different.

So to estimate your output code, you need the input voltage, the reference voltage and the resolution of the ADC. To get a better estimate you can include an uncertainity based on the integral non linearity (INL) of the ADC.

**Update:**

Based on the comment below, you have a note on the layout which tells you that 8A equal 1V, so the sense resistor is probably 250m\$\Omega\$. It is a simple linear relationship, so 4A will have 0.5V etc.

The value for your reference can be found: either in the data sheet of the used ADC (or if it is inside a microcontroller it's noted there), or if supplied externally in the data sheet of the reference used. Sometimes the reference is the analog supply voltage.

Comment: Thank you. I have two current (Amps) values. An actual current value (Iact) and a expected current value (Iexp).

**Iact= 8A** (1V=8A)(Input to ADC which gives 12 bit value which is unknown)
**Iexp= 4.6A** (varies during simulation, say 2.5A or 4.8A etc.)

The 12-bit ADC has a VRef=2.5V and R=1kΩ.

Comment: I want to find the approx. digital value of Iact so that I can use it to scale Iexp values to a 12bit value.

In this case, should I consider 1V as the input voltage or:

V=6A×1000Ω=6000V (which is too much)

Simply, I need a scaling method to get an approx. 12 bit value for the Iexp values. The Iact and Iexp are given as inputs to a PID controller.

Comment: @Alex I'm not completely sure I understand, if you say the ADC has \$R=1k\Omega\$ do you mean it's input impedance? You cannot put the current directly into the ADC, you have to convert it to a voltage first (be it a suitable shunt resistor or a current transformer)

Comment: Yes. Its the input impedance. Yes I understand that. But as a reference, I have it in the layout that 1V=8A is the input to the ADC. Should I consider it as 1V. What if it is 1V=9A( under diff current values)? How do I find the reference value to scale a incoming current(Amps) to a 12 bit value.

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer to include that rather important information which should have been put in the question in the first place.